# Regex matching more than two elements Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match two or more words in a string. The string is `My/word example/word` I want to extract `My example`. what I did so far is:

```
        String test = "My/word example/word";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((.*)\\/word){2,}");
        Matcher match = pattern.matcher(test);
        if (match.find()) {

                System.out.println(match.group(1));
            }
```

But it prints  `example/word` only, any ideas?

Comment: Can't you have `My` in one capturing group and `example` in another one? How general should that pattern be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have any repetition with a capturing group, it will only capture the final match of that group.  Your best option here would be to simplify the regex to only match one word, and then use `match.find()` repeatedly until you do not find a match:

```
String test = "My/word example/word";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)/word");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(test);
while (match.find()) {
    System.out.println(match.group(1));
}
```

It shouldn't be difficult to add some logic here to only print if you find two or more matches.

Also note that I modified your regex a bit, forward slashes don't need to be escaped and I replace `.*` with `\w+` which should be better because you won't greedily match up to the very last `/word`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the passive group for the `/word` part and iterate on the matched results to construct the final string.

```
String test = "My/word example/word";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w*)(?:\\/word)");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(test);
String result = "";
while (match.find()) {
    result += match.group(1) + " ";
}

System.out.println(result.trim());
```

The output will be:

```
My example
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the non-greedy *-operator:

```
((.*?)\/word)
```

Comment: Add on to this answer, get by group(2)

Answer (score 0):

Is is possible you are using the wrong group number? I think it would return the result you are looking for if you use `group(2)`